# Поведение высоты и ширины в em

Tags: html, css, css3

Добрый день почему `em` не слушаются, `font-size`.

Происходит такое на `chrome Версия 75.0.3753.4 (Официальная сборка), dev (64 бит)`.
Так же повторяется на `chrome Версия 73.0.3683.103 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)`.

Вверху как должно быть.

[image: Как должно быть]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Начинает работать как надо в выше указанных браузерах если указан font-size больше 6px.

```css
span:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    font-size: 1.3px;
    width: 10em;
    height: 11em;
    margin-right: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 11" style="fill:rgb(198, 161, 113);"><path d="M7.8,8.7C7,9.4,6.1,9.8,5,9.8c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-0.8,0-1.5-0.3-2.1-0.7l0.1,0.7v0c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.4 c0,0,0,0,0,0h0C2.2,10.2,2,10,2,9.8L1.9,8.2c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.4-0.4l1.6-0.1c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.4,0.4c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.4L3.2,8.4 C3.8,8.8,4.4,9,5,9c0.8,0,1.6-0.3,2.2-0.9c0.9-0.8,1.3-2.1,1-3.4C8.2,4.5,8.3,4.3,8.6,4.3C8.8,4.2,9,4.3,9,4.6 C9.4,6.1,8.9,7.7,7.8,8.7z"/><path class="st0" d="M1.7,6.3c0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0C1.2,6.8,1,6.6,1,6.4C0.6,4.9,1.1,3.3,2.2,2.3 c0.8-0.8,1.9-1.2,3-1.1C6,1.3,6.7,1.5,7.3,2l0-0.7c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.4-0.4C7.9,0.8,8,1,8.1,1.2l0.1,1.6v0c0,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.4 L6.2,3.3h0c0,0,0,0,0,0C5.9,3.3,5.8,3.2,5.7,3c0-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.4l0.6,0c-1.2-0.8-2.9-0.7-4,0.4C1.8,3.7,1.4,5,1.7,6.3L1.7,6.3z"/></svg>');   
}
```

```html
<span>Hello</span>
```

Comment: так оно и сейчас как должно быть - разве нет? к тому же font-size у вас в пикселях, а не в em

Comment: @humster_spb не во всех браузерах, так как должно, если поставить font-size на 0.01em например, в указанных браузерах ничего не измениться

Comment: хм.. хотя вот на самом деле в обычном хроме 73... не на всех компах повторяется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В некоторых браузерах по умолчанию стоит ограничение минимального размера шрифта. То есть, можно задать хоть 0.0001em,  но результат будет не меньше некоего заданного значения.

Делалось это с целью борьбы с Васями Пупкиными, которые использовали слишком мелкий шрифт по причине тупости или желания, например, насовать на страницу список ключевых слов текстом нулевого размера.

Так что: а) проверьте ваш браузер (у меня в современном хроме все норм) и б) не используйте инструменты не по назначению.